# Spring MVC nao reconhece pagina estatica - CSS

Tags: java, mvc, spring-mvc

Estou fazendo um projeto em java utilizando o Spring MVC e ao implementar a tecnologia minha pagina parou de ficar estilizada, ja procurei a solução em outras perguntas, na documentação do spring, e até acessei outros projetos que utilizam o Spring no GitHub, e as configurações estão iguais a do meu projeto. Não sei porque não funciona, se alguem quiser ver meu projeto inteiro está no GitHub https://github.com/Jo4o-Pedro/Sistema-Lanchonete-.git Mas acredito que pelas informações daqui conseguem me ajudar.
Aqui está a estrutura do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os metodos que estou usando na classe de configuração:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"lanchonete.com.br.sistemaaps"})

   public class AppWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

      // equivalent for <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> tag
     @Override
     public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
     }
   }
```

E o cabeçalho do meu jsp:

```
<%@page import="models.Usuario" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <title>Pagina Principal</title>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/estiloaps.css" />" />

</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei achando a solução que era a falta de duas dependencias:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.2-b02</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Após isso e com as configurações mencionadas na pergunta, funcionou corretamento